# How can I add the custom modes in Alexa smart home skill for fan?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I want to add the custom property field value for fan. What I want to achieve is below

​i.e:   *Alexa, set fan speed to 3*

​How can I achieve that ?

So is there any functionality in Alexa smart home skill to add the custom modes for fan?

Please help me , I am stuck at this point.
Any help would be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

Smart Home skills can use the [Alexa.PowerLevelController](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-powerlevelcontroller.html) and [Alexa.PercentageController](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-percentagecontroller.html) APIs to provide 0-100 control of devices. Either of these should work for controlling fan speed.

Comment: I want to add the custom modes in my AC device like "Turbo" and "Dry" like "Auto" ?

Comment: do you have any idea about this ? i am stuck here .

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. It might help to provide some examples of what you have tried already, and a description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Like Alexa provide by default "Auto , heat , cool " modes .So I want to add "dry" mode into this .
Now what is happening , when I say "Alexa , set main office AC to dry ".so she is telling us that "this device does not support this setting "

Comment: As documented by Amazon, with Alexa Smart Home skills "the voice interaction model is defined and handled for you". If you want to define different interactions then you'll need to create a custom skill instead.